# HTML Form within a compiled help file

Tags: html, forms, chm, helpfile

I am making a help file (.chm) for a project I am working on, but am having trouble with an HTML form element. What I want the form to be able to do is send an email so users can contact me about bugs, quetions, etc, but when I try the 'Submit' button, it notifies me that I am about to send the email, then crashes the Microsoft HTML Help Executable.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<TITLE> Contact me </TITLE>

<BODY>
<IMG SRC="banner.png" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="160" ALIGN="RIGHT" ALT="Banner">

<HR WIDTH="600" HEIGHT="5" ALIGN="RIGHT">
<P>

<H2 ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="Trebuchet MS">Contact me</FONT></H2>
</P>

<P><H4><FONT FACE="Trebuchet MS">Please enter the following details</FONT></H4>
<FONT FACE="Trebuchet MS">
    <FORM ENCTYPE="text/plain" METHOD="POST" ACTION="mailto:someone@example.com">
        Your name: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Name">

        <P>Details:
            <TEXTAREA ROWS="10" COLS="50" NAME="Details"></TEXTAREA>
        </P>

        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit">
    </FORM>
</FONT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Sorry about my terrible formatting, but hopefully you get the idea.

I have found that when I launch this in Google Chrome as a regular HTML document, it works fine and sends the email perfectly, but when I try it in Internet Explorer as an HTML, it crashes (typical). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A code block is inserted by indenting 4 spaces before any line of code. I've formatted the code for you this time, but please format it properly next time. For further help, see the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Using the `mailto` protocol as form action was already unreliable back in the late 1990s and has demonstrated to be of little value. I'm pretty sure that Microsoft hasn't dedicated any effort to ensure it remains functional in IE 7, 8, 9, 10... But let's wait and see if someone comes up with official reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's actually 100% possible, nor would I recommend it if it were.

I think a much better way would be to provide a link to a **Contact Me** page on your site, or simply provide your email in the body of the CHM.

### General Points

- UPPERCASING HTML tag names, while valid, is really annoying (subjective). A proper naming convention is where all HTML tags, attributes and keywords are lowercased.
- Use `<label>` elements when referring to form labels, example:

  ```
  <label>Your Name: <input type="text" name="Name"></label>
  ```

  This adds the nice bonus of making the "Your Name:" text clickable as well!